# Passing a subclass in a method that expects parent abstract class C++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods

I'm working on an assignment with the following (simplified) structure.

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual void method;
}

class B : public A
{
some variables;
public:
  void method;
}

class C
{
public:
  void method1(A *a);
}
```

I have a C instance and B instance and try to call c.method1(b), where b is my instance of class B.  However, it expects an A*, and gives me an error saying it can't convert B to A*.  I thought I would be able to pass instances of B in as they are subclasses of A.  How would I go about fixing this so I am able to pass B into the method, knowing that I can't change the method argument as it is part of the assignment?

Comment: "*the following (simplified) structure*" Please post real code. It's hard to guess what's "*simplified*" vs. what's plain wrong in the above. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert a `B` to a `A*`, but you can convert a `B*` to a `A*`.  I think you simply forgot this `&` operator:

```
main()
{
    B b;
    C c;
    c.method1(&b);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh that works, thank you so much.  Had some other errors after but got those to work since this was able to work